# Add components to JDialog

Tags: java, swing, colors, jdialog

When I run this, an empty title bar is displayed. I just want to be able to see the components and work from there, but nothing is displayed. The dialog is designed to allow the user to select a color by moving sliders, then return to color to the main page.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ColourDialog extends JDialog
{
    String colorNames[] = {"Red: ", "Green: ", "Blue: "};
    Label labels[] = new Label[3];
    JSlider slider[]= new JSlider[3];
    Label lb;
    static ColourDialog d;

    public void ColourDialog()
    {
        setModal(true);
        Container c = getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel sliderPanel = new JPanel();
        sliderPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        for (int i = 0; i < slider.length;  i++)
        {
            labels[i] = new Label(colorNames[i] + 255);

            sliderPanel.add(labels[i]);
            slider[i] = new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 255, 255);
            slider[i].setMinorTickSpacing(10);
            slider[i].setMajorTickSpacing(50);
            slider[i].setPaintTicks(true);
            slider[i].setPaintLabels(true);

            sliderPanel.add(slider[i]);
            //slider[i].addChangeListener(this);
        }

        lb = new Label("Colour");

        c.add(sliderPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        c.add(lb, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        setSize(500, 450);
        setLocation(200,200);
        setTitle("Colour Dialog");
    }

    public static Color showDialog()
    {
        if (d == null)
        d = new ColourDialog();

        d.show();

        //return new Color(red,green,blue);
        return new Color(0,0,0);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        ColourDialog.showDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `d.show()` do?

Comment: ColourDialog extends JDialog, so d.show() makes the dialog visible, right?

Comment: The comment on in the JDialog API says that `.show()` is deprecated and that you should use `setVisiable(true)`

Comment: Thanks. I don't think it is the source of the problem however because I still see an empty dialog, so it is visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might be because you say "public void ColourDialog()" this is an invalid constructor. Try getting rid of the "void" and try again.

Comment: This is all I had to do and my code works. Moments when you love programming.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you have look at [JColorChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html), this `JComponent` can returns selected `Color`

there I can't fout out correct definitions and initializations for [JSlider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/slider.html)

EDIT

there are lots of mistakes starting with extends JDialog end with public static Color showDialog(), that returns empty container typos with initializations for ColourDialog()

[image]

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class ColourDialog {

    private JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
    private String colorNames[] = {"Red: ", "Green: ", "Blue: "};
    private Label labels[] = new Label[3];
    private JSlider slider[] = new JSlider[3];
    private Label lb;

    public ColourDialog() {
        JPanel sliderPanel = new JPanel();
        sliderPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
        for (int i = 0; i < slider.length; i++) {
            labels[i] = new Label(colorNames[i] + 255);
            sliderPanel.add(labels[i]);
            slider[i] = new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 255, 255);
            slider[i].setMinorTickSpacing(10);
            slider[i].setMajorTickSpacing(50);
            slider[i].setPaintTicks(true);
            slider[i].setPaintLabels(true);
            sliderPanel.add(slider[i]);
        }
        lb = new Label("Colour");
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setModal(true);
        dialog.add(sliderPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        dialog.add(lb, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        dialog.pack();
        dialog.setLocation(200, 200);
        dialog.setTitle("Colour Dialog");
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                ColourDialog colourDialog = new ColourDialog();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the tip. May I ask if you see anything in the code that is leading to this outcome? I'd really like to see this work... thanks again.

Comment: @Joe nobody knows this code snipped missed start and end, maybe you mixing JComponets, maybe only typo(s), battery not included, for reall help you have to edit your question with [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You never call the method ColorDialog().  This is a good spot to mention "start methods with a lower case letter). To fix you code:

Change:

```
    d = new ColourDialog();
```

To:

```
    d = new ColourDialog(); 
    d.ColourDialog();
```